# 401 on Google JS Client API

Tags: google-api-js-client

I'm brand new to this API and am trying to work through this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api using the newer code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/tree/master/samples/analytics/v3). I keep getting a 401: Unauthorized response but my clientID, apiKey, and scopes are all set correctly in auth_util.js.

I never see the 'Authorize' button, whether I am logged into Google or not which seems fishy.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: in auth_util.js, find

> ```
> function checkAuth() { gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId,
> scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult); }
> ```

and change `true` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hello Analytics API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) have been updated recently. Some of the key steps that people often have issues with is setting the AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS. If you are testing an application on your local machine on port 8080 you should log into the developer console and set this value to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```